# Port 443 works but not https

Tags: ssl, https

I have a website setup, if I load the website with `http://www.url.com:443` it works as expected, but if I load `https://www.url.com` I get a "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" error on Chrome.

I have setup iptables to load port 3000 through both port 80 and 443.

Server is running centos, there is no ssl certificate setup at this stage

Comment: What does "load port 3000" mean?

Comment: @mm759 I have a node server running at port 3000

Comment: What is in the address bar after you loaded www.url.com:443? http or https?

Comment: @mm759 sorry updated the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You configured the server to listen on port 443 but didn't configure it for SSL traffic.  In other words, you merely changed the port from 80 to 443, so it is serving HTTP on port 443.

You say there are no SSL certificates set up.  That's the problem.  You need to set up certificates (even if only self-signed ones) for HTTPS to work at all.  It's the key and certificates from this setup process that tell the server how to encrypt the HTTPS data, and how to identify itself.

This page will help you to set things up properly: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Https

There are many places you can look for advice on creating keys and certs, but the easiest and least expensive options are StartSSL and LetsEncrypt.  Both will do this for you at no cost.

https://letsencrypt.org/

https://www.startssl.com/

Comment: Normally that would return a different error message about the website being unsecured though wouldn't it? That's my experience

Comment: If you have no key or certs, SSL cannot work.  It uses the KEY to encrypt the data it sends.  Chrome likely gives this error because it tries to communicate in SSL and the server sees invalid responses and closes the connection.  To be clear, if you have no key and certs, the server CAN NOT communicate in SSL.  Listening on port 443 is not enough.

Comment: See this confuses me, as other websites I have if I go to https.. where its not setup, I get a `Your connection is not private`  error. so I'm confused as to different error messages

Comment: The "your connection is not private" may be related to using self signed, expired, or otherwise invalid certificates.

Comment: Google lists these errors together: "Your connection is not private" or "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" or "ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID", implying that the error is from badly configured certificates, not from NO certs.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869?hl=en